# is there something wrong with my sql expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Report v8.5 to display the list of the clients who're still have balance.

Below is the SQL expression I wrote

```
SELECT
    "c"."firstname","c"."lastname"
    "transaction"."record", "transaction"."balsheet"
FROM
    "dbproj"."dbo"."c" "c"
    "dbproj"."dbo"."transaction" "transaction"
INNER JOIN
    "dbproj"."dbo"."c" "c" ON "c"."clientid"="transaction"."clientid"
WHERE
    ("transaction"."tstatus"='UNPAID')
ORDER BY
    "c"."lastname"
```

I'm new in Crystal Reports, so I did a thorough research on how to convert SQL statement into a SQL expression, and that's what I got. But when I put this on SQL expression, the messagebox indicates that there is an error with the expression used.

Is there anything I still need to improve? Or the fact that I placed this query on SQL expression fields was a terrible idea? I saw a demo on a youtube channel so I am (for somehow) confident that what I did is right, but if so, why do I receive this error message?

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: remove this line: `>"dbproj"."dbo"."c" "c"` (leave this line: `>"dbproj"."dbo"."c" "c" ON`)

Comment: Why are you putting double quotes around every single name? That makes your query extremely difficult to parse. Instead of `"c"."firstname"` why not just `c.firstname`?

Comment: @Aaron, Crystal will actually show you single quotes around every name. So it should look more like 'c'.'firstname'. But it usually works without any quotes.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 why on earth does Crystal do that? With single quotes those look like string literals, not identifiers, and some forms of that syntax have been deprecated anyway ([documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) and elsewhere). I hope this isn't how it works in the most recent and future versions (if they are still being produced).

Comment: @Aaron, I'm not sure why CR does that. I've always found it strange myself. I use CR 2008 and it's still shown that way.

Comment: You seem to be missing a comma after `"c"."firstname","c"."lastname"`' as it stands, `"c"."lastname"` is being renamed to `"transaction"."record"`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd love to see the youtube video that gave you this syntax, because it's wrong - either you transcribed it incorrectly, or the publisher should have their SQL license taken away.

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, t.record, t.balsheet
------ missing comma here ----^

FROM 

----- extra reference to the table "c" removed here

dbproj.dbo.[transaction] AS t -- used an alias here too, just like c below
INNER JOIN dbproj.dbo.c AS c
ON c.clientid = t.clientid
WHERE t.tstatus = 'UNPAID'
ORDER BY c.lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `FROM` clause should be just:

```
FROM

"dbproj"."dbo"."transaction" "transaction"
```

The full query:

```
SELECT

"c"."firstname","c"."lastname",

"transaction"."record", "transaction"."balsheet"

FROM

"dbproj"."dbo"."transaction" "transaction"

INNER JOIN

"dbproj"."dbo"."c" "c" ON

"c"."clientid"="transaction"."clientid"

WHERE

("transaction"."tstatus"='UNPAID')

ORDER BY

"c"."lastname"
```

Comment: This still has a syntax error (no comma after lastname in the select list).